# Autofill a form in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, autofill

I am using WordPress for building my own website, And I created a form using  WP form plugin and users are supposed to fill this form after entering the site and I want parts of the form to be filled automatically for them according to the login information, i.e. name.
So my question is, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery or javascript, take ID of that field and run ajax on page load you will get info of use logged in and put that in your field by using jquery parameter .val()